# How do you authenticate a GitHub App in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, github-api, github-app, octokit-js

I've created a new GitHub App and I'm trying to authenticate from Node. I'm new to GitHub Apps, for example, I don't know what "installationId" is supposed to be. Is that the App ID?

I successfully get a token using a private key, but when I try using the API, I get an error both from Node and from curl.

```
import { createAppAuth } from '@octokit/auth-app';
import { request } from '@octokit/request';

const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + 'file.pem');
const auth = createAppAuth({
 id: 1,
 privateKey,
 installationId: 12345,
 clientId: 'xxx.xxxxxx',
 clientSecret: 'xxxxxx',
});

const appAuthentication = await auth({ type: 'app' });
console.log(`Git repo token: ` + appAuthentication.token);

const result = await request('GET /orgs/:org/repos', {
      headers: {
                 authorization: 'token ' + appAuthentication.token,
               },
               org: 'orgname',
               type: 'public',
      });
return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Git result: ' + result });
```

Here is the curl example I tried after getting the token from the Node code above.

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxx" -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.machine-man-preview+json" https://api.github.com/app
```

The result in Node: "Git result: Git repo error: HttpError: Bad credentials"

Result in curl: 
{
  "message": "Integration not found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}

Comment: Re-check your request headers, you are using `'token '`. I believe you may have to use `'Bearer '` instead

Comment: @kn_pavan thanks for the suggestion. I did try that. You'll see the curl example above uses Bearer.

Comment: Can you try following:
To identify installation_id: [Get Installations](https://developer.github.com/v3/apps/#list-installations)
[Authenticating as GithubApp - check authentication as installation section](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-github-apps/authenticating-with-github-apps/#authenticating-as-a-github-app)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The JSON Web Token (JWT) authentication can only be used for a few endpoints of GitHub's REST API. Mostly the ones listed on https://developer.github.com/v3/apps/

For all others, you need an installation access token.

Can you try this instead?

```
const { token } = await auth({ type: "installation" });
const result = await request("GET /orgs/:org/repos", {
  headers: {
    authorization: "token " + token
  },
  org: "orgname",
  type: "public"
});
```

Note that the `installationId` option must be set to a valid installation ID. You get the installation ID when you install the GitHub app on github.com. For example, you can install the WIP app at https://github.com/apps/wip on your account or any organization you have admin access to. The installation URLs look like this:

https://github.com/settings/installations/90210

In the example above, the installation ID is `90210`.

To simplify your code, you can use the `auth.hook` feature in which case the correct authentication will be set automatically based on the URL

```
import { createAppAuth } from "@octokit/auth-app";
import { request } from "@octokit/request";

const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "file.pem");
const auth = createAppAuth({
  id: 1,
  privateKey,
  installationId: 12345
});

const requestWithAuth = request.defaults({
  request: {
    hook: auth.hook
  }
})

const result = await requestWithAuth("GET /orgs/:org/repos", {
  org: "orgname",
  type: "public"
});
```

See https://github.com/octokit/request.js/#authentication for more examples

Comment: Thx! I’ll try this tonight. Really really appreciate the clarification

Comment: Thx again. It worked with your revised/simplified code once I understood where to get the Installation ID.

Answer (score 4):

Anyone landing here and using Octokit, here is a newer way of doing it:

```js
const config = {
  appId: process.env.GITHUB_APP_ID,
  privateKey: base64ToAscii(process.env.GITHUB_PRIVATE_KEY),
  webhooks: {
    secret: process.env.GITHUB_SIGNING_SECRET,
  },
};

const app = new App(config);

// Get installationId from the installed app or a webhook event
const octokit =
  await app.getInstallationOctokit(installationId);
const { data: user } = await octokit.rest.users.getByUsername({
  username: login,
});
```